# How to show the cost of a game using this Python

Tags: python

How could I show the cost of a game using Python, using code something like this:

```
if game_list[game]>= 10:
                print ("The Price for this Game is: $"), game_prices[game]*1.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is python3.x you have to do it as follows:

```
if game_list[game]>= 10:
    print ("The Price for this Game is: $", game_prices[game]*1.1)
```

For python2.7, it would be:

```
if game_list[game]>= 10:
    print "The Price for this Game is: $"+game_prices[game]*1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better to delegate the price-setting logic:

```
def game_price(game):
    price = game_list[game]

    if price >= 10:
        markup = 0.1
    else:
        markup = 0.2

    return price * (1. + markup)

print("The game's price is ${:0.2f}".format(game_price(game)))
```